# Base URL in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, angular-routing

While dveloping my AngularJS app on my local WAMP server it resides in:

```
http://localhost/Projects/myLaravelProject/public/
```

When calling routes as

```
$http.post("/login", sanitizeCredentials(credentials));
```

It is trying to access

```
http://localhost/login
```

and obviously getting a 404 error, i have no idea how to overcome this. Im using Hashbang mode not HTML5 mode

Comment: are you using real html5 mode or hashbang?

Comment: hashbang mode not html5 mode

Comment: I guess this is relevant when you define links and routes with routeprovider. wouldn't it be alright (but noisy...) to have a service with a constant that is just your base url? or just configure properly your server so that the root is the root and not "Projects". and a quick check: try '#/login'

Comment: i do like that solutions although i think the best case is ashit's making a virtual host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't your create a virtual host? so your url will be yourapp.dev
and angular will make request to yourapp.dev/login which is correct.

Or else if you are using Laravel4, use PHP Development Server

```
php artisan serve
```

that's what I do always.